# How to show that a statement in sets is false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to show that a statement in sets is false and prove its negation is true?

For example I have the exercise:

Let's say that $E$ is a non-empty set and $A,B,C$ $\subseteq$$E$.For each $Α,Β,C$ how to show that the equation $(Α-Β)-C=A-(B-C)$ does not apply?

Should we try to find a counterexample in these situations?

Comment: There is some trouble with your wording. Mainly, that the equation _does_ apply to _some_ $A, B, C$. For instance, if $C$ is disjoint from the two other sets, then both sides degenerate into $A-B$. Therefore it's not true, as you wrote, that "for each $A, B, C$ the equation does not apply". However, "for each $A, B, C$ the equation applies" is not true, and I assume that's what you're supposed to show.

Comment: Counterexample should do fine. You can use a sketch.

Comment: As for why the equation is not always true, here's some intuition: On the left-hand side, you start with $A$, remove one part of it, then remove a second part of it. On the right-hand side, however, you start with $A$, and you take away something smaller than the first part you removed above, and you never remove the second part. Making a counterexample would mean simply making sure the second part is relatively large, since that's the big difference between the two sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Venn diagram solution, masterfully drawn in Paint.

Top: The three sets.
Bottom left: $(A-B)-C$ in black.
Bottom right: $A-(B-C)$ in black.

[image: Venn diagram]

We can easily see that the two differ by exactly $A\cap C$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like these kind of solutions!

Comment: @MarkoPolo The best part is, they're really easy to make, and pretty powerful. All you need is pen and paper and the ability to draw circles (and of course interpret set notation). Then it all solves itself. Of course, the moment there is a $D$ and maybe an $E$ and $F$ mixed up in there as well, it gets difficult, but for two or three sets it works wonders.

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample would be sufficient and just writing A=B=C={a} would disprove the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to find a counterexample.

To do this, it would help to draw a venn diagram or simplify the statement:

\begin{align} (A-B)-C&\overset{?}{=}A-(B-C)\\
(A \cap B^c)\cap C &\overset{?}{=} A \cap (B \cap C^c)^c \\
(A \cap B^c)\cap C &\overset{?}{=} A \cap (B^c \cup C) \\
(A \cap B^c)\cap C &\overset{?}{=} (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap C) \\
\end{align}

---

Note: As Arthur commented, the position of the "for each $A,B,C$" in your statement makes it ambiguous; here I assumed you meant to show it is false that

> For all subsets $A,B,C$ of $E$, $(A-B)-C = A-(B-C)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.First I simplified the statement and then I drew a venn diagram to show that the statement its false by counterexample.

Comment: Venn diagrams are great for leading you to counterexamples. Make sure in your counterexample you write out the elements are in $A,B,$ and $C$. (I'm not sure a venn diagram alone constitutes a counterexample.)